# Problem with py2app / PIL Crashing MacOS to Logout on Different Machines

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library, python-3.8, py2app

This is basically a desktop app to take region screenshots and save to a selected folder with incrementing number filenames. Nothing fancy and uses only PIL and Tkinter libs.

- All is fine if I am running .py or .app file from the development
  machine.
- Running .py file in any other machine without lib append gives PIL Module not found
  error on IDE.
- Running .app in any way crashes the app to logout
  screen.

I've tried a few methods to solve the issue; like --includes=PIL, adding packaging info options, adding actual library files to .app library files folder, appending library path.

I've been banging my head around this for the past 2 days and I feel like I'm running in a circle and there is not much precedence on the issue to follow around.

Here are the files:

**main.py**

```
import sys
sys.path.append("lib/python3.8/") # latest attempt to show PIL files. 
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog, simpledialog
from tkinter import ttk

from PIL import ImageTk, ImageGrab, ImageEnhance

# if platform() == 'Darwin':  # How Mac OS X is identified by Python
#     system('''/usr/bin/osascript -e 'tell app "Finder" to set frontmost of process "Python" to true' ''')
#     subprocess.call(["/usr/bin/osascript", "-e", 'tell app "Finder" to set frontmost of process "Python" to true'])

root = tk.Tk()
root.resizable(0, 0)
root.geometry("210x400+0+0")
root.title("Erkan Ulu Crop Aracı")
root.iconbitmap("bitmap.ico")
root.configure(bg="#1F2020")

# logo = tk.PhotoImage(file="app-logo.png")
logo = tk.PhotoImage(file="appicon.png")

# Theme Options
path_to_theme = "./awthemes-9.4.2/"
root.tk.call('lappend', 'auto_path', path_to_theme)
root.tk.call('package', 'require', 'awdark')
style = ttk.Style()
style.theme_use("awdark")

# Label Config
style.configure("TLabel",
                padding=(10,10,10,10),
                justify=tk.CENTER,
                font="Open-sans 10")

# Button Config
style.configure("TButton",
                width=20,
                justify=tk.CENTER,
                font="Open-sans 10 bold")

folderPath = tk.StringVar()
folderPath_View = tk.StringVar(value="Başlamadan Önce\nLütfen Klasör Seçiniz.")

file_name = 1
question_no = tk.StringVar(value="1")
question_text = tk.StringVar(value="Çekilen Soru No: ")

default_path = "~/Desktop"


def set_file_name():
    global file_name
    file_name = simpledialog.askinteger("Soru No:", "Başlanacak soru numarasını yazınız.", parent=root)
    question_no.set(file_name)
    print("Sayı numarası ayarlandı")


# def set_pre_file_name():
#   global file_name
#   file_name = simpledialog.askinteger("Soru Öncesi İsim", "Soru İsminin Başına Yazılaca ", parent=root)
#   question_no.set(file_name)
#   print("Soru Öncesi İsim Ayarlandı")


def undo_image(event):
    global file_name
    file_name -= 1
    area_sel(event)
    print("Görsel tekrar çekiliyor")


def reset(event):
    global file_name
    file_name = 1
    print("Sıfırlandı")
    return file_name


def set_folder_name():
    folder_selected = filedialog.askdirectory(initialdir="~/Desktop")
    folderPath.set(folder_selected)
    view_path = str(folder_selected)
    X_path = view_path.rsplit("/", 1)[1]
    folderPath_View.set(X_path)
    root.update()
    global file_name
    file_name = 1
    question_no.set(file_name)
    print("Klasör Ayarlandı: " + folder_selected)


def area_sel(event):
    x1 = y1 = x2 = y2 = 0
    roi_image = None


def on_mouse_down(event):
    nonlocal x1, y1
    x1, y1 = event.x, event.y
    canvas.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x1, y1, outline='red', tag='roi')


def on_mouse_move(event):
    nonlocal roi_image, x2, y2
    x2, y2 = event.x, event.y
    canvas.delete('roi-image')  # remove old overlay image
    roi_image = image.crop((x1, y1, x2, y2))  # get the image of selected region
    canvas.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(roi_image)
    canvas.create_image(x1, y1, image=canvas.image, tag=('roi-image'), anchor='nw')
    canvas.coords('roi', x1, y1, x2, y2)
    # make sure the select rectangle is on top of the overlay image
    canvas.lift('roi')

    root.withdraw()
    image = ImageGrab.grab()
    bgimage = ImageEnhance.Brightness(image).enhance(0.25)
    win = tk.Toplevel()
    win.attributes('-fullscreen', 1)
    win.attributes('-topmost', 1)
    canvas = tk.Canvas(win, highlightthickness=0)
    canvas.pack(fill='both', expand=1)
    tkimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(bgimage)
    canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=tkimage, anchor='nw', tag='images')
    win.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', on_mouse_down)
    win.bind('<B1-Motion>', on_mouse_move)
    win.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', lambda e: win.destroy())
    win.bind('<Escape>', lambda e: win.destroy())
    win.focus_force()
    win.grab_set()
    win.wait_window(win)
    root.deiconify()
    if roi_image:
        global file_name
        folder_name = folderPath.get()
        # folder_name = "/Users/anil/Desktop/testfolder"
        convert_img = roi_image.convert("RGB")
        save_path = folder_name + "/" + str(file_name) + ".jpeg"
        file_name += 1
        question_no.set(file_name)
        save_format = "JPEG"
        convert_img.save(save_path, save_format)
        # show_image(convert_img, file_name-1)
        # root.focus_force()
        # root.focus_set()
        # root.mainloop()
        print("Soru Çekildi")

        root.update()  # new_image_question()

#PADDING = (SOLA, YUKARI, SAĞA, AŞAĞI)
ttk.Label(root, image=logo).pack()
ttk.Button(root, text="Klasör Seç\nBaşla", command=set_folder_name).pack()
ttk.Label(root, textvariable=folderPath_View, font="Open-sans 12", padding=(0,10,0,20)).pack()
ttk.Button(root, text="Başlanacak Soru\nNumarasını Seç", command=set_file_name).pack()
ttk.Label(root, text="Çekilecek Soru No:",padding=(0,10,0,0)).pack()
ttk.Label(root, textvariable=question_no,padding=(0,0,0,0), font="Open-sans 12").pack()
ttk.Label(root, text="Soru Ekle = S Tuşu\nSoruyu Tekrar Çek = T Tuşu").pack()

root.bind('<Key-s>', area_sel)
root.bind('<Key-t>', undo_image)
root.bind('<Key-Escape>', reset)

root.mainloop()
```

**setup.py**

```
"""
This is a setup.py script generated by py2applet

Usage:
    python setup.py py2app
"""

from setuptools import setup

APP = ['main.py']
DATA_FILES = ["logo.png","bitmap.ico","awthemes-9.4.2","appicon.icns","appicon.png"]
OPTIONS = {
    'iconfile':'appicon.icns',
    'argv_emulation': True,
    'site_packages': True,
    'use_pythonpath': True,
    'packages': ['PIL', 'tkinter'],
    'includes': ['PIL','tkinter','ImageTk']
}

setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    version="1",
    name="Crop Tool",
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
    install_requires=["Pillow"]
)
```

**Compilation errors:**

```
Modules not found (unconditional imports):
 * PyQt5.QBuffer (PyQt5.QtCore, PyQt5.QtGui)
 * PyQt5.QIODevice (PyQt5.QtCore, PyQt5.QtGui)
 * PySide2.QBuffer (PySide2.QtCore, PySide2.QtGui)
 * PySide2.QIODevice (PySide2.QtCore, PySide2.QtGui)
 * _gdbm (dbm.gnu)
 * _overlapped (asyncio.windows_events)
 * cffi (PIL.Image, PIL.PyAccess)
 * cffi.FFI (PIL.Image)
 * com (com.sun.jna)
 * com.jna (com.sun)
 * com.sun (com.sun.jna.platform)
 * numpy (PIL.ImageFilter)
 * olefile (PIL.FpxImagePlugin, PIL.MicImagePlugin)
 * ordereddict (pkg_resources._vendor.pyparsing)
 * win32com (win32com)
 * win32com.shell (win32com.shell)
 * win32com.shellcon (win32com.shell)

Modules not found (conditional imports):
 * Image (/Users/anil/PycharmProjects/ULUCrop-V2/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py2app/recipes/PIL/prescript.py)
 * PySide2 (PIL.ImageQt)
 * PySide2.QtGui (PIL.ImageQt)
 * StringIO (pkg_resources._vendor.six)
 * cffi (PIL.ImageTk)
 * com (pkg_resources._vendor.appdirs)
 * com.sun.jna (pkg_resources._vendor.appdirs)
 * com.sun.jna.platform (pkg_resources._vendor.appdirs)
 * win32com (pkg_resources._vendor.appdirs)
 * win32com.shell (pkg_resources._vendor.appdirs)
```

Comment: Your code is very long. Please always provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to make it easier for others to understand your problem and to help you.

Answer (score 0):

The `Modules not found`-messages are mostly harmless.

From your description (everything working well on your development machine where all the libraries are installed but not working on another computer without the libraries) it seems like you may be using py2app with option `-A` or `--alias` (i.e., `python setup.py py2app -A`) and thus, creating a development version that does not include the libraries (see [py2app Option Reference](https://py2app.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#option-reference)). If this is the case, remove the `-A` option and use just

```
python setup.py py2app
```

to produce an .app including all the libraries.

If you don't use the `-A` option and get an error message about a missing library anyway, please copy & paste the full error message; it may contain extra information to make it possible to help you further.